# Getting the result of a SearchResponse in ElasticSearch

Tags: java, mongodb, elasticsearch

I am trying to use ES as the index for my MongoDB. I've managed to integrate them successfully, but I find the search API rather complex and confusing. The Java API is not too helpful either.

I am able to find exact matches, but how can I get this result? Here is my code:

```
Node node = nodeBuilder().node();

SearchResponse sr = node.client().prepareSearch()
        .addAggregation(
            AggregationBuilders.terms("user").field("admin2san")
            .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("SPT").field("64097"))
        )
        .execute().actionGet();

SearchHit[] results = sr.getHits().getHits();
List<Firewall> myfirewall = results.getSourceAsObjectList(Firewall.class);
for (Firewall info : myfirewall) {
       System.out.println("search result is " + info);
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate it a little bit more?
What do you want as end result?

Comment: I want to display  the result in Sytem.out.println for this query.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I understood your question.

If you want to print the result of your searchResponse according to your example it should be something like this :

```
SearchHit[] results = sr.getHits().getHits();
for(SearchHit hit : results){
    String sourceAsString = hit.getSourceAsString();
    if (sourceAsString != null) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat(dateFormat)
                .create();
        System.out.println( gson.fromJson(sourceAsString, Firewall.class));
    }
}
```

I'm using Gson to convert from the Json response to the FireWall(POJO).

I hope it's what you were looking for.

Comment: I added something to format your date parameter into a defined DateFormat

Comment: No Resulat :( Samy can you give me your adress ?

Comment: if results is empty then your resuest must have no response. make sure your data sample should have results. 
If results is not empty and Gson failed to convert from Json to POJO, make sure that the fields returned in ElasticSearch are the same from the Object FireWall.

Comment: @SamyElaiassi- What if I have any List variable available in the Firewall class?

Answer (score 1):

response.getHits().getHits()[0].getSourceAsMap() you could try somwthing like this