# Transform SearchHit to Java Object in ElasticSearch

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch

I am trying to retrieve data form ES query and I am confused about how can I transform each hit of retrieved data to Java Object. 
Until now, I can get each hit in JSON format using Gson but I think is useless to transform from Hit to JSON and then to Java Object.

My current code is:

```
TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY)
            .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"), 9300));
    Settings settings = Settings.builder()
            .put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch")
            .put("path.home", "/Users/user/Apps/elasticsearch-5.4.1")
            .build();

    QueryBuilder qb = termQuery("price", 12);
    SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("kal").setTypes("products")
            .setSearchType(SearchType.DEFAULT)
            .setQuery(qb)
            .get();

    SearchHit[] results = response.getHits().getHits();
    for (SearchHit hit : results) {
        String sourceAsString = hit.getSourceAsString();
        Map<String, SearchHitField> responseFields = hit.getFields();
        if (sourceAsString != null) {
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat(sourceAsString)
                    .create();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve there. You practically already have the java objects (the SearchHit array named results ). Do you want to get a reference to a child object of a SearchHit?

Comment: Is there a direct way to map the SearchHit to another Object? 
Or you need to implement constructor?

Comment: If you see here 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30376770/4343294
you retrieve JSON object from SearchHit

Comment: oh, i see.. you want to get the source of SearchHit and map it to another custom object? or do you need the whole SearchHit?

Comment: This code is working:
SearchHit[] results = response.getHits().getHits();
        for (SearchHit hit : results) {
            String sourceAsString = hit.getSourceAsString();
            Map<String, SearchHitField> responseFields = hit.getFields();
            SearchHitField field = responseFields.get("product_id");
            Map map = hit.getSource();
            System.out.println(map.toString());
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented this solution but I am not sure if this is the proper way or not.

```
SearchHit[] results = response.getHits().getHits();
    for (SearchHit hit : results) {
        String sourceAsString = hit.getSourceAsString();
        Map<String, SearchHitField> responseFields = hit.getFields();
        SearchHitField field = responseFields.get("product_id");
        Map map = hit.getSource();
        System.out.println(map.toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

One line

```
YourObject yourObject = new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper().convertValue(searchHit.getSourceAsMap(), YourObjectClass.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    I am working with Elasticsearch version 7.4.2

    SearchHit[] searchHit = response.getHits().getHits();
            for (SearchHit hit : searchHit) {
                String jsonString=hit.getSourceAsString();
                TempClass tmpCl=(TempClass )JSONToObject.parser(jsonString, TempClass .class);
                System.out.println(tmpCl.toString());
            }


    // JSONToObject class
    private static Object dc;
    public static Object parser(String file, Class<?> cls) {
        try {
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                dc = gson.fromJson(file, cls);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return dc;
    }
```

Comment: Please add explanation to your answer.